# How to specify a path to an Objective-C bridging header?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, bridging-header

I'm trying to make a bridging header but where would I specify the path in my build settings?

Comment: Prompt doesn't always add the path to Build Settings -> Swift Compiler - Code Generation -> Objective-C Bridging Header as mentioned by Eugene

Answer (score 7):

**Creating Bridging Header File for Manually**

When not generating **Bridgin-header** file automatically, then you can check and follow the below step for creating new **Bridging-header-file** manually.

1.Create a new header file and name it like **"your project name-Bridging-Header.h"**. The file must be saved to your project folder

2.Select your xcode project -> select your build target -> select build settings -> click the "all" option at the top -> **Search for Swift Compiler - General**

3.Select **Objective-C Bridging Header** item and double click on its value field (right side of the same row). One popup would appear and there you can enter your bridging header file path (Follow the below steps to provide header file path).

4.Open finder and drag and drop your bridging header file to the popup. Now it will create an absolute path for bridging header. To make relating path, you can give the path as **$(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/$(PROJECT_NAME)-Bridging-Header.h**

5.Click outside for the value get saved. Done!! Now you can import your Objective-C libraries (eg. **#import "StringMapping.h"**) to bridging file.

6.Clean your project (eg. **Ctrl+shift+k**) and build your project (eg. **Ctrl+B)** and start using it in your swift project.

i hope its usefull for you.

Answer (score 3):

Go to your target's Build Settings -> Swift Compiler - Code Generation -> Objective-C Bridging Header -> the path should be `<#Project name#>/<#Project name#>-Bridging-Header.h`

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is just to add a file in the other language. Xcode will offer to create the bridging header. Accept. The bridging header will be created and the build settings will be pointed to it.

Comment: I didn't say it necessarily would pop up. (After all, if you were offered this option and rejected it, you have turned off that dialog.) I said this was the easiest way (i.e., when you are initially offered this option, do _not_ reject it).